# Code Randomly Changing a State Element to 1

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Working on a project that will allow you to search the Spotify database for songs, add it to a playlist, then add the playlist to your account, I run into an error when attempting to add a song to a playlist. Upon searching through the code to find and reason, and adding console logs to see where it goes wrong. It seems that in the render statement, the state element `playlistTracks` is changed from an Array with the added song inside it as an object to just the integer 1. This image shows the progression of console logs: 
[image]

This is the code from App.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import SearchBar from '../SearchBar/SearchBar';
import SearchResults from '../SearchResults/SearchResults';
import Playlist from '../Playlist/Playlist';
import Spotify from '../../util/Spotify.js';


class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   searchResults: [],
   playlistName: 'New Playlist',
   playlistTracks: []
  }
  this.addTrack = this.addTrack.bind(this);
  this.removeTrack = this.removeTrack.bind(this);
  this.updatePlaylistName = this.updatePlaylistName.bind(this);
  this.savePlaylist = this.savePlaylist.bind(this);
  this.search = this.search.bind(this);
 }

 addTrack(track) {
  console.log(track);
  if(this.state.playlistTracks.length !== 0) {
   const ids = Playlist.collectIds(this.state.playlistTracks);
   let newId = true;
   for(let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    if(ids[i] === track.id) {
     newId = false;
    }
   }
   if(newId) {
    this.setState({playlistTracks: this.state.playlistTracks.push(track)});
   }
  } else {
   this.setState({playlistTracks: this.state.playlistTracks.push(track)});
  }
  console.log(this.state.playlistTracks);
 }

 removeTrack(track) {
  const ids = Playlist.collectIds(this.state.playlistTracks);
  let trackIndex = -1;
  for(let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
   if (ids[i] === track.id) {
    trackIndex = i;
   }
  }
  if (trackIndex !== -1) {
   const newPlaylist = this.state.playlistTracks.splice(trackIndex, 1);
   this.setState({playlistTracks: newPlaylist});
  }
 }

 updatePlaylistName(name) {
  this.setState({playlistName: name});
 }

 savePlaylist() {
  let trackURIs = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < this.state.playlistTracks.length; i++) {
   trackURIs.push(this.state.playlistTracks[i].uri);
  }
  Spotify.savePlaylist(this.state.playlistName, trackURIs);
  this.setState({playlistName: 'New Playlist', playlistTracks: []});
 }

 async search(term) {
  const results = await Spotify.search(term);
  this.setState({searchResults: results});
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <div id="root">
      <h1>Ja<span className="highlight">mmm</span>ing</h1>
      <div className="App">
        <SearchBar onSearch={this.search} />
        <div className="App-playlist">
        {console.log(this.state.playlistTracks)}
           <SearchResults searchResults={this.state.searchResults} onAdd={this.addTrack} />
           <Playlist 
            playlistName={this.state.playlistName}
            playlistTracks={this.state.playlistTracks}
            onRemove={this.removeTrack}
            onNameChange={this.updatePlaylistName}
            onSave={this.savePlaylist}
           />
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `error` is likely a result of `pushing` and `mutating` `state` in one line.

Try:

```
// Add Track.
addTrack = (track) => this.setState({playlistTracks: [...this.state.playlistTracks, track]})
```

Answer (score 2):

`Array.prototype.push` returns the new number of elements in the array. It does not return the array itself.  You are setting the state to the returned value, which is 1.

Here are some examples to illustrate what's happening:

What you expect to happen:

```
let someArray = [];
someArray.push('something');
console.log(someArray); // -> ['something']
```

But what you are actually doing is akin to:

```
let someArray = [];
someArray = someArray.push('something');
console.log(someArray); // -> 1
```